# Order of multiple variables in Matlab solve equations

Tags: matlab, equation-solving

I read [Matlab documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve.html) and still have difficulty understanding order of multiple variables in Matlab solve equations

For example

```
syms f1(R,L) f2(R,L);
f1 = (80+R)^2 + (120*pi*L)^2 - 232^2;
f2 = R^2 + (120*pi*L)^2 - 176^2;
[R,L] = solve (f1,f2);
fprintf('Resistor is %s Ω\n',round(R,3));
fprintf('Inductance is %s H\n',round(L,3));
```

If I replace variable `L` with `Z`, result will be in inverse order.
It seems to be alphabetical order and I have no idea what the exact rule it is.

Comment: Hi 陳旭祺, welcome to SO! This is expected behavior; according to the built-in help, "For several variables and several outputs, the results are sorted in the same order as the variables `var1,var2,...,varN` in the call to `solve`.  In case no variables are given in the call to `solve`, the results are sorted in lexicographic order and assigned to the outputs." For some peace of mind, you could call `solve()` with a single output argument, `X=solve(...)` , to get a struct with meaningful field names (`X.L, X.R`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the documentation for [`solve`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve.html) that you linked:

> `Y = solve(eqns,vars)` solves the system of equations `eqns` for the variables `vars` and returns a structure that contains the solutions. If you do not specify `vars`, `solve` uses [`symvar`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/symvar.html) to find the variables to solve for.

You don't specify which variables to solve for, so MATLAB attempts to deduce this by calling [`symvar`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/symvar.html). The order of the identifiers returned by `symvar` doesn't appear to be documented explicitly, so I would not recommend relying on any particular ordering.

If you want to specify which variables `solve` should solve for, and hence their order in the output, pass them in an array as the second argument of `solve`:

```
[R, L] = solve([f1, f2], [R, L]);
```